# Peculiar background CSS design

Tags: html, css, background, css-shapes

I would like to make a CSS background on "div" with a specific design and this design should be responsive (width and height). You can view the example generated with the properties "border" inside "div" with properties "position absolute" and separated the other "div", but this example isn't correct because when I increase the screen, the width isn't 100%.

Image (color purple and transparent):
[image]

Code:

```css
.trape {
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 2000px solid;
  border-right-color: #b60f80;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="trape"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 text-centeR">
      <h2 class="white">¡TEXT MODEL!</h2>
      <p>SIMULATION TEXT ALING MIDDLE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Conclusión:

I would like to generate the css background responsive with the image exemple unused "border" and want to be able to put the text or other elements inside in the same div.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you not use svg?

Comment: I didn't work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use gradient and multiple background:

```css
.box {
  color:#fff;
  padding:30px 0 30px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,#b60f80 49%, transparent 51%) bottom/100% 30px no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(to top left,#b60f80 49%, transparent 51%) top/100% 30px no-repeat,  
   linear-gradient(#b60f80,#b60f80) center/100% calc(100% - 60px) no-repeat;
}

body {
 background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque luctus lectus vel viverra tincidunt. Quisque vitae malesuada justo, nec porttitor felis. Sed aliquam sem turpis, sit amet pharetra ex blandit luctus. Morbi facilisis vel est eu interdum. Sed semper, erat a molestie tincidunt, purus velit luctus dolor, nec tristique ex neque eget tortor. Vestibulum a rhoncus ex. Aenean neque massa, porta a nulla non, faucibus pretium magna
</div>
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque luctus lectus vel viverra tincidunt. Quisque vitae malesuada justo, nec porttitor felis. Sed aliquam sem turpis, 
</div>
```

Comment: I implemented the new design but in IE10 and IE11 not work correctly, the design seen bad....    :(

Comment: @user3387682 Ah, still using the dead IE :p ... I thnk the issue is with the calc I have used, it's will be difficult to find an alternative

Comment: i tested change 49% to 50% and 51% to 50%, now in IE work correctly but in others browsers the slanted line appears ill-defined